# What does "I had cut my eyeteeth" mean?

Tags: meaning, translation

What does "I had cut my eyeteeth" mean? And how can I translate it in Italian language?

A sample text is as follows:

> As an intelligence officer, and even before that as a young student in the course of my studies at the British Museum in London, I had **cut my eyeteeth** on all of them, plus a good number of others with whom I imagined Americans were familiar.

Comment: a simple dictionary search reveals much!

Comment: Translating into Italian is really for the https://italian.stackexchange.com/ site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Cut my [eye]teeth on" is an idiomatic expression meaning "to gain early experience." Typically, it refers to one's first experience with a subject. I don't know any Italian idioms, but you could translate the sentence instead as: **"As an intelligence officer, and even before that …, I had gained experience with all of them, plus a good number of others …"**

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+eyeteeth+on

Answer (score 2):

In English, an eyetooth is a canine tooth in the upper jaw, and a baby "cuts teeth" when teeth initially emerge in the baby's mouth. Figuratively, "to cut one's eyeteeth on X" means "to become familiar with and adept at dealing with X very early in one's life or in one's professional development."